# Do item frames and the items they contain prevent/reduce creeper blast damage?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I just had a creeper blow up in my house and the house seemed to suffer almost no damage (a few wooden wall and floor blocks broken). Only the 16 item frames and items they contained, which were all side by side in a 4x4 pattern on the wall next to where the creeper exploded, were all left broken and floating nearby. So I was wondering, do item frames and the items they contain act like "ablative armour" and absorb the shock of the explosion or was it just weird luck that my house wasn't destroyed (the walls and floor are all wood and glass).

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't believe so. All items in item frames will be dropped (Popped out of their item frames) and have the same Blast Resistance.